# Sort new products magento

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I'm developing a magento webshop. On my homepage I display the newly added products. I want to sort those, preferably by colour.

home xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" 
 template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">  
    <action method="setProductsCount"><count>100</count></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
</block>
```

I tried adding an attribute called "kleur" which can be used to sort. After that I put these next two lines in this block and that did not work.

```
    <action method="setDefaultOrder"><field>kleur</field></action>
    <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>asc</dir></action>
```

I also tried to set the "kleur" field in the display settings of the category. And last but not least I also tried to set it in the configuration->category.

On the web I can't find more solutions to the problem.

Is there any other way, except editing the template file to sort the new products.

I hope I gave you enough information to be able to give some advice, if you need more don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Login to Admin Panel
2. Go to: Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes, then edit the Attribute which want to use in sorting.
3. Under Frontend Property you will get a field "Used for Sorting in Product Listing", set it's value to "Yes"
4. Then, reindex, if required.

Now set this attribute for sorting from admin or from xml depend upon, what your block is reading.

If, you are using magento default block for sorting, then

Go to: System->Configuration->CATALOG/Catalog->Frontend->Product Listing Sort by: Select Attribute

If, reading xml for sorting, then

```
<action method="setDefaultOrder"><field>Attribute_Code</field></action>
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>ORDER (asc/desc)</dir></action>
```

Hope will help!